# Vuetify wrap v-columns

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-row that is built like this:

```
<v-row class="mt-3 d-flex flex-wrap">
    <v-col cols="4">
        <v-text-field
            v-model="search"
            placeholder="Suche"
            filled
            rounded
            dense
            width="50"
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
        >
        </v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="3">
        <v-menu
            ref="menu1"
            v-model="menu1"
            :close-on-content-click="false"
            transition="scale-transition"
            offset-y
            max-width="290px"
            min-width="auto"
        >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="BeginDate"
                    label="Startdatum"
                    persistent-hint
                    prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
                    v-bind="attrs"
                    color="primary"
                    v-on="on"
                >
                </v-text-field>
            </template>
            <v-date-picker
                color="primary"
                v-model="BeginDate"
                no-title
                @input="menu1 = false"
            >
            </v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="3">
        <v-menu
            ref="menu2"
            v-model="menu2"
            :close-on-content-click="false"
            transition="scale-transition"
            offset-y
            max-width="290px"
            min-width="auto"
        >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="EndDate"
                    label="Enddatum"
                    persistent-hint
                    prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
                    v-bind="attrs"
                    color="primary"
                    v-on="on"
                >
                </v-text-field>
            </template>
            <v-date-picker
                color="primary"
                v-model="EndDate"
                no-title
                @input="menu2 = false"
            >
            </v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="1">
        <v-btn
            @click="DateFilter()"
            color="primary"
        >
            Apply
        </v-btn>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="1">
        <v-btn
            @click="DateFilterReset()"
            color="red"
            class="white--text"
        >
            Reset
        </v-btn>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

On the website if you visit it on Desktop it looks perfectly fine:
[image: Row on Desktop]

But if you go on the Site on a device with a smaller screen size, the columns aren´t wrapping.
[image: Row on a smaller device]

Does anyone know the classes i need to apply to the v-row. I have already tried 'd-flex' and 'flex-wrap'. I didn´t find any more helpful on the vuetify website either. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cols` attribute define the col width for all viewports. To set a different col width in small viewport you should use the `xs` or `sm` attributes. For ex:

```
<v-col cols="4" xs="12" sm="6"></v-col>
```